# In pytorch data parallel mode, how to use the global tensor?

Tags: mpi, pytorch

In this example, I wish the `z_proto` could be global for different GPUs. However, in the data parallel mode, it is split into different GPUs as well. How to solve such a problem? Thank you.

```
class SequencePrototypeTokenClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,seq_model, label_num):
        super(SequencePrototypeTokenClassification, self).__init__()
        self.seq_model = seq_model
        self.label_num = label_num

    def forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask, labels, z_proto, n_query, target_inds):
        z, _ = self.seq_model(input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask, output_all_encoded_layers=False)
        z_dim = z.size(-1)
        zq = z.squeeze().view(-1, z_dim)
        dists = euclidean_dist(zq, z_proto)
        log_p_y = F.log_softmax(-dists, dim=1).view(-1, self.label_num)
        loss_val = -log_p_y.gather(1, self.target_inds).squeeze().view(-1).mean()
        _, y_hat = log_p_y.max(1)

        return loss_val, y_hat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `DataParallel` would only replicate the `nn.Parameter` of the `nn.Module`. So I random initialized a `nn.Parameter` named `z_proto` in the module and copy the value of tensor `z_proto` into the parameter. Then the parameter is replicated into 4 GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your above code, `z_proto` seems to be one of the arguments of the forward function and not part of the model. Therefore, simply storing it in a `tensor` on the main GPU would enable it to have the same value across GPUs.

#### Edit

Based on [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#dataparallel-layers-multi-gpu-distributed), it seems that `DataParallel` splits all the inputs to the forward pass function across the GPUs. A method by which you can circumvent it is by storing it as a class variable inside the model object itself. You can update the value before calling the forward function if it's not a static variable.

```py
class SequencePrototypeTokenClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,seq_model, label_num):
        ...
        self.z_proto = None
        ...
        ...


#Training loop
    ...
    model.z_proto = value
    model.forward()
    ...
```

Comment: I put the ```z_proto``` on the main GPU. But ```replicas = self.replicate(self.module, self.device_ids[:len(inputs)])``` in the ```DataParallel ``` would split the ```z_proto``` onto the 4 GPUs.

Comment: Hi I tried this method. ```proto_model.module.z_proto = z_proto``` But it got ```RuntimeError: arguments are located on different GPUs at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generated/../generic/THCTensorMathPointwise.cu:272```

Comment: That's weird. According to the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#dataparallel-layers-multi-gpu-distributed), pytorch does the splitting only during the forward call and merges it back before the next line. Are you sure you have put `z_proto` updates outside the `forward()` function? And have you initialized `z_proto` in the `__init__` function?

Comment: Yeah, I did almost exactly the same thing as yours. I initialized the ```z_proto``` with ```None``` and update it before ```forward``` but using only GPU 0. I thought ```z_proto``` would be replicated with the ```module``` but it wasn't.

Comment: Can you share your complete code along with the training loop?

Comment: I figured out. It seems only ```nn.Module``` can be replicated. So the ```z_proto``` will keep the same.